# Raspberry Pi master, Arduino I2C slave. Return data to master Raspberry Pi from other service

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

Raspberry Pi is sending commands and reading data from Arduino via I2C.
Everything is done this way:

1. Raspberry send a command to Arduino and read a response.
2. Arduino sends command (on or off) to dali power supply and gets a response. It takes about 40 ms.

On Raspberry Pi, it's not getting updated response.
How to wait until `loop()` is done reading data? And then send to the Raspberry Pi? I can not wait because some commands should be repeated at less than 100 ms.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include "dali.h"

volatile bool state = false;
volatile uint8_t response = 0;
volatile bool newCommand = false;

void setup() 
{
dali.Init(A0, 7);
dali.busTest();
dali.transmit(BROADCAST, RECALL_MIN_LEVEL);
Wire.onReceive(ReceiveEvent);
Wire.onRequest(RequestEvent);
Wire.begin(10);
}
void loop() 
{
if (newCommand)
{
    Serial.println(state);
    response = dali.GetData(state);
    Serial.println(response);
    newCommand = false;
}
}

void ReceiveEvent(int howMany)
{
byte req;
while (Wire.available())
{
    req = Wire.read();
}
if (req == 97)
{
    state = !state;
    newCommand = true;
}
}
void RequestEvent()
{
Wire.write(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add `Serial.begin()` into the setup and then tried to call `Serial.print()` in the loop, this may be freezing your Arduino.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was adding Serial.begin (9600) but it did not help. Now I've added one control contact. When responded by receiving a response from a dali power supplay. He's digitalWrite (8, LOW). Raspberry pi waits until it is low and then only tries to scan the data. But maybe the better option is to solve the problem?